# Set BUILD_TESTING to OFF by default using CTest

Tags: cmake, ctest

When you do `include(CTest)` in CMake it includes [this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/0d1bf3f660faebd8b73d638d0359db5502e2f3d6/Modules/CTest.cmake#L50) line:

```
option(BUILD_TESTING "Build the testing tree." ON)
```

I want tests to be not built by default (but overridable on the command line). How can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

Ah this seems to do the trick:

```
option(BUILD_TESTING "" OFF)
include(CTest)
```